# How can I build a regular expression to match a single word?

Tags: python, regex

Say I had the following strings:

```
Dublin, Ireland. 
DublinIreland
Ireland, Dublin
```

What regular Expression could I use to find the word `Dublin` in the above strings, but, it cannot count `DublinIreland`. As in, `DublinIreland` doesn't say `Dublin`, it is a whole word that says `DublinIreland`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit : this answer referred to OP's first question, and it actually still answers is second :-p
Use boundaries, such as \b. `\bwent\b` would match went.

Answer (score 0):

This would match all capitalised words:

```
/\b([A-Z][a-z]+)\b/
```

Or just the word 'Dublin':

```
/\bDublin\b/
```

Comment: good thinking but that's going to match Ireland too wouldn't it?

Comment: Oh, you just want to match *'Dublin'*? Sorry, I thought that was just an example; this will work: /\bDublin\b/

Answer (score 0):

In some languages you can use () to specify a selection and then reference the first selection with $1 or 1.

Comment: In this case you can use /Dublin[^[:alpha:]]/

Answer (score 0):

This should match ever instance of Dublin in your sample, but you will have to look at the match groups because it would also capture the I in DublinIreland.

```
/(\bDublin)(\b|[A-Z])/g
```